# Codename One - TextField appearance

Tags: codenameone

I have a GUI built app and am trying to emulate the TextFIeld look of the Yahoo Mail page, where the underline of the TextField turns to blue when pressed.
[image]

I changed the "pressed" and "selected" state of the TextField UIID, but it only changes when I press it, but it doesn't stay that way and it turns back to grey.

**Question:**
Is there some kind of "toggle" function in TextFields as in CheckBoxes, so the new state stays that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only selected state is used in text field (not pressed) and it should remain blue. It seems this is an issue with [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/) possibly a recent regression due to recent changes to text editing.

I've filed an issue on that [here](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1652).